# What settings can enhance the picture quality?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What settings can enhance the picture quality?
Level? Sharpness?

I tried these in photoshop but the out come result still has a poor resolution.
[image]

Comment: This is a page (5) out of the book "Are You My Mother?". If you purchase the book (USD 5) you can scan the page at higher resolution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a slight change in style, you can try using [various ESRGAN neural models](https://upscale.wiki/wiki/Model_Database) to enhance the image. This is what I got from 0.5 bicubic downscale + ArtClarity + UltraYandere:

[image]

This does cause typical artifacts of neural networks, but it shouldn't be too hard to fix these with a brush, as the image is relatively simple.

Comment: This is an excellent wake-up signal for those of us who haven't been vigilant enough to see what AI based tools are available.